# Byron-Fuller mathematics of classical and quantom physics chapter 3

Tags: linear-algebra

"show that the operator" T = I + xD/ 1! + (xD)^2/ 2! + · · · + (xD)^n/ n! ,where D = d/dt [and x is a constant], acts as a translation operator on the space of polynomials (in the variable t) of degree ≤ n, that is, T f(t) = f(t + x), if f(t) is in the space of polynomials of degree ≤ n.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** $D$ is a linear operator and $1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^n$ span the space of polynomials in $t$ of degree $n$. So, it suffices to show that $Tt^k=(x+t)^k$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$. Note that $D^rt^k=0$ for $r=k+1,\,k+2,\,\ldots,\,n$.